# Ansible ec2 module ignores "volumes" parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to get Ansible to bring up new ec2 boxes for me with a volume size larger than the default ~8g. I've added the `volumes` option with `volume_size` specified, but when I run with that, the `volumes` option seems to be ignored and I still get a new box with ~8g. The relevant part of my playbook is as follows:

```
- name: provision new boxes
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
        group: "{{ aws_security_group }}"
        instance_type: "{{ aws_instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ aws_ami_id }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_vpc_subnet_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ aws_key_name }}"
        wait: true
        count: "{{ num_machines }}"
        instance_tags: "{{ tags }}"
        volumes:
        - device_name: /dev/sda1
          volume_size: 15
      register: ec2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: `ansible --version`: ansible 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

So, I just updated ansible to 1.9.4 and now all of a sudden it works. So there's my answer. The code above is fine. Ansible was just broken.